# How to get dynamically subMaterial index?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I would like to get the index of the SubMaterial dynamically by the pickResult.pickedmesh in order to specify it like :

```
pickResult.pickedMesh.material.subMaterials[3].diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.9, 0.6, 0));
```

I would like to get the "3" dynamically to add a color per face.
Is it possible ? How can i do it ?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem :)

```js
pickResult.pickedMesh.material.subMaterials[pickResult.subMeshId].diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0.9, 0.6, 0.3)
```